# Smooth geometry after a bevel operation

Tags: faces, subdivision-surface, bevel

Noob question here.
I'm sure this one is as simple as they come but for the life of me i cannot figure this out!

Mesh cube resized; scale applied.
Applied a bevel operation (CRTL+B) on the 4 smaller edges (just 4 segments)
[image: After Bevel Operation]

In the long run, if i want to bump the resolution of the mesh (Subdivide Operation) to get rid of the ugly faces on the round parts, the result is the same as the subdivision doesn't affect the ugly low poly aspect.
[image: After Subdivision Operation]

The result is the same even if i add a Subdivision Surface Modifier (Simple). Even after applied the aspect remains the same...
[image: Subdivision Surface Modifier]

By any chance this is a very simple "thing" to fix (as i suspect) or i have to bump the segments all the way up as soon as i do the Bevel Operation?

Many thanks on advance!

Edit:
Many thanks for those you've help me with this noob question!
Got the answers i need! Thanks!

In case someone is curious on where i wanted to implement the knowledge:
[image]

Simple i know... and i want to make proper holes in the geometry so all the elements just do not poke through each other like that!

Again, thank you all very much for the help!

[Blend File](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1QPYjMYff_WzTYFf7LokUG3Jd5gEMg4K5/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure that you need more subdivision? To make an object look smooth, maybe a simple *Shade Smooth* is enough. Depending on your topology you may need to activate the *Object Data panel > Normal > Auto Smooth* option.

In your case, don't use the *Subdivide* operation, it will only add edges between existing edges but won't round the topology, and as it will add edges, it will even tend to keep the faces flat, like a support edge do. Even with a *Smoothness* of 1 it won't work as you expect.

If you really need additional topology, what you need to do is use the *Subdivision Surface* modifier instead, as it will round the shape, and then apply it if necessary (don't apply if it's not necessary). Don't forget to create bevels on the top and bottom faces otherwise these faces will bend.

Low-poly with *Shade Smooth* and *Auto Smooth*:

[image]

Low-poly with *Shade Smooth*, with a bevel at the top and bottom, it doesn't need any *Auto Smooth*, thanks to the bevels:

[image]

Low-poly with *Shade Smooth* and a *Subdivision Surface* modifier: It adds virtual faces (it may not be necessary, depending on your needs), and it doesn't go round thanks to the bevels:

[image]

Comment: As i already said, i tried with a Subdivision Surface Modifier too and the result was exactly the same... Simple as Catmull-Clark completely destroys the geometry :) I attached a Blender file with the beveled geometry. Please check it if you can...

Comment: Shade Smooth rounds all parts of the geometry like a balloon. I want just the round parts to be smooth. Shade Smooth + Auto Smooth 30º helps but the top flat part is very noticeable...

Comment: You may need to activate the *Auto Smooth* to avoid bad shading. As for the Subdivision Surface modifier, you need to create bevels (support edge loops) on the top and bottom faces, otherwise they will bend.

Comment: Also, are you sure that you need such a dense topology? If not, don't subdivide, just shade smooth to get a round shading

Comment: It doesn't here! In Object mode, right-click and select Shade Auto Smooth. Then maybe increase the Angle to around 80 degrees in the bottom-left properties panel. You might also bevel the edges first to 5 or 6 segments which will give you a better result on an object of that size.

Comment: @JohnEason
Bevel the 6 edges again worked almost 100% Thanks! Although if so, it's better to bevel them more on the start ;)

Comment: @moonboots
Low poly with Shade Smooth + Subdivision Surface Modifier on beveled edges (top and bottom) works great! Thanks!

Comment: Edited the Original post to thank all for the help and link an image to the almost final version of what i was working on.

Comment: you're welcome  ;)  ........